# Drupal, How to create a side bar menu with a pop out module/panel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal, panel

I am trying to create a sidebar navigation alot like this website:
http://www.josephleonard.com/

I am currently using the Adaptive Theme in drupal and using panels. I have the whole layout perfectly. All I need to figure out is how to trigger a panel after selecting an item on the menu as it does on this website. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to hide your pop out panel by default. display: none; then use JQuery to show your pop out panel when a menu link is clicked. See this post for both a CSS and jQuery solution. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/styled-popup-menu/